# How can I declare a .txt file as a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a text file whose Unicode characters I'd like to read one-by-one using `charCodeAt()`. Is there syntax I can use to declare the contents of the file as a string by specifying the URL of the text file?

EDIT: I have the following code using jQuery [as recommended below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682405/how-can-i-declare-a-txt-file-as-a-string/6682477#6682477):

> ```
> var t;
> var music = function(source){
>         $.get(source, function(data){
>         t = data;
>     });
> }
> music('music.txt');
> alert(t.length);
> ```

But the alert is presently `undefined`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) and, when loaded, the data will appear in [responseText](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute).

Browser variations mean it is a good idea to [use a library](http://microjs.com/#ajax).

Comment: Yes, but how? Please see edit above. Sorry I didn't provide the code sooner.

Comment: Process the data **in the callback**. The variable won't have been set before the HTTP request comes back.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem exactly. One solution is to make the request asynchronous using `$.ajax([...]asynch:false)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use $. Ajax instead of $. Get, so you can configure the call to the asynchronous mode (async: false), this will force the browser to wait for the execution of AJAX call before continuing processing.

Note the jquery documentation: "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active."

```
var t;

var music = function(){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/music.txt", 
        dataType: "text", 
        sucess: function(data){
            alert(data);
            t = data;
        }
    });
};
music("music.txt");
alert(t.length);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As best I know, you would have to use an ajax call to read the file into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlHttpRequest, jquery or AJAX to read the text file using its URL, then parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

[The issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886681/how-can-i-pass-data-from-an-ajax-request-to-a-global-variable) was the problem. Upon making the request synchronous, I was able to define `t` in line with my script.